# Replace error message with file

Tags: php, foreach

I have this piece of code:

```
private function grabCurrentUser() {

    $this->id = parent::secure($_GET['cid']);

    $params = array( ':user_id' => $this->id );
    $stmt   = parent::query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id;", $params);

    if( $stmt->rowCount() < 1 ) parent::displayMessage("<div class='alert alert-error'>"._('No such user!')."</div>");

    foreach ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $field => $value)
        $this->options[$field] = $value;

}
```

I want to replace the error message on it, so instead of having this error message:

```
parent::displayMessage("<div class='alert alert-error'>"._('No such user!')."</div>
```

I want to include index.php like so:

```
include_once(cINC . 'index.php');
```

So how can I replace it from showing an error message to just including index.php?

I tried this:

```
private function grabCurrentUser() {

    $this->id = parent::secure($_GET['cid']);

    $params = array( ':user_id' => $this->id );
    $stmt   = parent::query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id;", $params);

    if( $stmt->rowCount() < 1 ) include_once(cINC . 'index.php');

    foreach ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $field => $value)
        $this->options[$field] = $value;

}
```

But got this error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had mistake in application logic, if you don't have any records and want to include some file then you don't iterate through empty record list.

```
private function grabCurrentUser() {

    $this->id = parent::secure($_GET['cid']);

    $params = array( ':user_id' => $this->id );
    $stmt   = parent::query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id;", $params);

    if( $stmt->rowCount() < 1 ){
        include_once(cINC . 'index.php');
    } else {
        foreach ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $field => $value)
            $this->options[$field] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an include, to do what you want, use a redirect like:

```
header(index.php);
```

Right, with that out of the way, redirecting an on error is a *REALLY BAD THING*. Why don't you error trap it out, understand what is going on with the code, and write it in a way so that it *cannot* generate that error in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

you must try to catch the error, when the user id is not known, so you could do the following

```
if( $stmt->rowCount() < 1 ) 
{
include_once(cINC . 'index.php');
exit();
}
else {
foreach ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $field => $value)
$this->options[$field] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just guess that `parent::displayMessage` terminates the current script execution, so the following `foreach` is not being executed with invalid arguments. Your `include_once` does not terminate the script and the `foreach` is run...

`return` from the function, `die()` or do something else that stops the `foreach` from running.